# Php returning list in params of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get a list of array options and insert this list in a params value, The below is an example of what the output should be. I am using wordpress and say I wanted the array to be a list of all pages or user roles. Where I have the Engineer & FM role this will need to be a dynamic list based on the user roles available in wordpress.

```
 array(
        "type" => "dropdown",
        "holder" => "div",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __( "Select the type of user", "my-text-domain" ),
        "param_name" => "type",
        "group" => __( 'User', 'my-text-domain' ),
        "value" => array(
        'engineer' => 'engineer',
        'fm' => 'fm'),
        'save_always' => true,
        "description" => __( "Pick a dropdown option.", "my-text-domain" )
     ),
```

As above I want to insert a list of arrays here ( my_array_values ) but they will be dynamic so need to know how to insert the returned into the below as the format above is outputted?

```
 array(
        "type" => "dropdown",
        "holder" => "div",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __( "Select the type of user", "my-text-domain" ),
        "param_name" => "type",
        "group" => __( 'User', 'my-text-domain' ),
        "value" => array(
        my_array_values),
        'save_always' => true,

        "description" => __( "Pick a dropdown option.", "my-text-domain" )
     ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as:

```
$foo["value"] = array("engineer" => "engineer", "fm" => "fm");
```

Comment: How would I add this?
array(
        "type" => "dropdown",
        "holder" => "div",
        "class" => "",
        "heading" => __( "Select the type of user", "my-text-domain" ),
        "param_name" => "type",
        "group" => __( 'User', 'my-text-domain' ),
        "value" => array(
        $foo),
        'save_always' => true,

        "description" => __( "Pick a dropdown option.", "my-text-domain" )
     ),

Comment: If I do the following it returns only the last entry ? array( "type" => "dropdown", "holder" => "div", "class" => "", "heading" => __( "Select the type of user", "my-text-domain" ), "param_name" => "type", "group" => __( 'User', 'my-text-domain' ), "value" => array( $foo["value"]), 'save_always' => true, "description" => __( "Pick a dropdown option.", "my-text-domain" ) ),

Comment: Can you maybe edit your original question to include what you are doing in PHP to insert the array, what the output is and what you want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer answer and think I was adding an array to an array. Below works!

$foo = array('engineer' => 'engineer', 'fm' => 'fm');

```
array(
    "type" => "dropdown",
    "holder" => "div",
    "class" => "",
    "heading" => __( "Select the type of user", "my-text-domain" ),
    "param_name" => "type",
    "group" => __( 'User', 'my-text-domain' ),
    "value" => $foo,
    'save_always' => true,

    "description" => __( "Pick a dropdown option.", "my-text-domain" )
 ),
```